# Having problem with Blender export into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

Recently I was trying to make a animation of a flying carpet, but I had one problem. After exporting with FBX, I could find my object at Unity Scene but unfortunately without animation.
They way I am trying to do that: I am animating in edit mode of Blender and successfully I have done the carpet move but the problem is that I can't export my animation, I can export only my object (basically, I can see my animation at unity project assets but it doesn't work there). Any ideas what is going on?

P.S. the animation was from a older animation and for some reason it was the only one that got download. I didn't need this one so I deleted it, but still my main animation didn't get download.

From Unity:
[image: From unity]

Blender Export:
[image: Blender Export]

Blender Export:
[image: Blender export]

Full image of my carpet in Blender and keyframes:
[image: Full image of my carpet in blender and keyframes]

Answer (score 0):

But here are those things you can check and try once:

- On the export menu of the blender, check if bake animation has a tick mark on it.
- After importing it to unity. Expand your mesh in the project browser and you may find an animation clip inside. If you do see it then you exported it the right way. Not click on the animation clip and press [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>] based on what OS you're using and duplicate it. Now open the duplicated clip on the animation tab. You will find your animation with their keyframes, then press [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>] copy[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>] those keyframes.
- Now put your mesh into the hierarchy
- Add an animator component to it or with it selected in hierarchy look down at the animation tab. you will find "Create an animation for this gameobject" Click okay name a animation and paste those keyframes you have copied.
- By doing it, this should work. Your carpet should now have the animation you made.

When exporting any model with animation from blender. Unity doesn't default put the animation for us. So, we need to manually do it this way. By creating a animation controller, and adding the clip that comes by importing the model.

Comment: Okay , so i found out that my clips werent from my carpet and i didnt rly need them. Now as i can see, my carpet have any clip. I upload some images at my question. Thanks for helping me